# Google Calendar API - Service Account Error

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Im trying to create a calendar application with "service account" and I downloaded the newest version of the google-api-php-client

And when i access serviceAccount.php i get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method apiClient::setAssertionCredentials() in /home/fmentert/public_html/reservations/google-api-php-client/examples/calendar/serviceAccount.php on line 44

this is my serviceAccount.php file. I added my client id, service account name and key file.
ALSO. I changed const to define()
my php version is 5.2.17

```
define('CLIENT_ID', '896988357842.apps.googleusercontent.com');
define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME', '896988357842@developer.gserviceaccount.com');

// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't
// readable by others.
define('KEY_FILE', 'bqwe3287e42d1c2342349f4c9769asdas55-privatekey.p12');

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Prediction Sample");

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the
// Google API Console when the service account was created.
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new apiAssertionCredentials(    // THIS IS LINE 44
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),
  $key)
); ....
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: The code that you posted, is trying to get the token from the wrong url. The url https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction is for the prediction service. For the calendar service you need https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar. As the respond below points our, you need to include the apiClient.php file, and ADD to the file src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php  From reading your code, I infer that you copy pasted the code w/o reading the notes or looking at the logic of the code to make work for your purpose

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at las version. You can get the solution there:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-php-client/vZysbW_XgiQ/-4kSFWP8UtEJ%5B1-25%5D

I fix it using the 475 version. With it the example works fine.

Salut!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not including the file that contains the definition for the `apiClient` class.  To this, use the `require_once` command.

For example, if the `apiClient` class is defined in a file called "apiClientFile.php", then your PHP script would look like this:

```
require_once 'apiClientFile.php';

define('CLIENT_ID', '896988357842.apps.googleusercontent.com');
...
```

Comment: Hi.
I actually did, just didn't paste it here along with all the comments on top. so it starts with .... comments, comments, comments ->
require_once '../../src/apiClient.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/apiPredictionService.php';

And I did look for the newest version

Comment: Well the error message says that it can't find a method called "setAssertionCredentials" in the "apiClient" class.  Try opening up apiClient.php and see if you can find the method you need.  It could be that you're using the wrong method name.

Comment: THANX--- Aha. Yes, you'r right... i was not able to find setAssertionCredentials in the newest version of
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

And when i go to "source" on:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/apiClient.php?r=399
i get correct files... but will i have to download them all one by one... is that the problem?

(one-by-one) because i get different errors now.

Comment: The source code that you see there is still under development and may contain bugs.  I would suggest waiting for them to release a new, stable version (for example 0.5.1 or 0.6.0).  But if you really need to use this method, instead of downloading the files one by one, you can checkout the entire project using Subversion: `svn checkout http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-php-client-read-only`